What you are not
You are not Paul Carrack.
You are not David Copperfield.
You are not Annie Sullivan.
You are not Albert Einstein.
You are not Loretta Lynn's father.
You are not a house builder.
You are not Sigmund Freud.
You are not a moving staircase.
You have not been hoist by your own petar.
What are you?

Is the knowledge tag applicable here?

I think probably not.

Are you sure there is  absolutely no need to reference some kind of external knowledge source like Wikipedia?

A little bit of knowledge, perhaps, but nothing particularly obscure. I think that the majority of  people will get it once they see the answer.

Is the typo in the last line deliberate?

Figuring that out is part of the puzzle.

@Pete https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/66620746#66620746

Unless I'm confused, this definitely needs that knowledge tag, because I think I am

 a doctor

and this puzzle is about

 the various times Dr McCoy said "I'm a doctor, not a ..." on Star Trek.

Consulting

 the start of the list at https://www.ditl.org/paglistdoctornota.php (I have no idea how authoritative it is)

we see:

 House builder: "I'm a doctor, not a bricklayer!" (The Devil in the Dark)
 Freud: "I'm a surgeon, not a psychiatrist!" (The City on the Edge of Forever)
 Einstein: "I'm not a scientist or a physicist, Mr. Spock..." (Metamorphosis)
 Moving staircase: "I'm a doctor, not a escalator!" (Friday's Child)
 Carrack: "I'm a doctor, not a mechanic!" (The Doomsday Machine)
 Hoist with one's own petar (this is not a typo, it's how Shakespeare wrote it): "I'm a Doctor, not an engineer!" (Mirror, Mirror)
 Copperfield: "I'm not a magician, Spock, just an old country doctor." (The Deadly Years)
 Loretta Lynn's father: "I'm a doctor, not a coal miner!" (The Empath)

This leaves

 Annie Sullivan (must be "miracle worker")

but

 since OP, in comments on the question, seems keen to insist that there's "nothing particularly obscure" here, I shall refrain from going to further effort to try to determine where that one occurs :-).


I'm guessing "house builder" is the first in your list, which you currently have unlabeled

that is correct.

D'oh, I'm an idiot; will fix that.
